# cant mount windows drive share to ubuntu server

Tags: mount

I have been trying to mount an SMB share to my VIM4 (a single board computer) running Ubuntu Server, but no matter what I get `mount error(13): Permission denied`. I can mount the SMB share on a laptop running Kali with no problem and I was able to mount the SMB share on the VIM4 when it was running Ubuntu Desktop.

Fenix 1.5 Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS Linux 5.4.180

```
sudo mount -t cifs //x.x.x.x/Local_Share /mnt/share -o username=LocalUser
Password for LocalUser@//x.x.x.x/Local_Share:
```

Comment: **Welcome the Ask Ubuntu community.** Can you please edit your question to include the version of the Ubuntu OS that you're running? This will help in diagnosing your issue. Thanks